# Combining multiple drill through reports into one

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, drillthrough

First time posting here so please be kind.
I've come from using PowerBI to achieve pretty much everything I need to with a couple of clicks to using SSRS 2008... and I'm having a hard time. Here's what I'm trying to do:

I have a main report that summarizes some data on how long it takes to close down help desk tickets. On that report I have a table with summary figures (ie 220 tickets were picked up after 5 working days, 18 tickets were reopened etc). I want to click the text-box that contains 220 and be taken to a drillthrough report that contain the same table with column headers and just different row sets in each case. There will be 8 drill through actions in total and I currently have 8 drill through reports. Only 2 of those are parameter based, the others just filter the dataset based on some conditions.

What I'm trying to work out is this: can my 8 drill-through reports be rolled into one, if they're just different views of the same dataset? I've created some calculated columns with values (Yes/No because boolean doesn't allow multiple values) which are easier to pass to parameters. I also have 8 parameters on my detail data set. I've set up actions (where `parameter1 = yes` for instance) to take me to my detail report and use the corresponding parameter each time. It should work... but it doesn't and I can't work out why. Currently its' complaining that I can't compare a boolean to an int16 - neither the value in my calculated column nor the default parameter value is boolean or int. So, am I trying to do something that just isn't possible? Has anyone else achieved this?

Edit: here's the parameter

[image: Parameter]

[image: Default parameter values]

The error I'm getting is

[image: error description]

The calculated column that should be checked against the parameter is

```
=IIF(IsNothing(Fields!DatePickedUpByAgent.Value), "Yes", "No").
```

Here's how I defined the action to take me to the drill through report in this case

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XlfQV.png]

Here are the filters on the subreport dataset based on the parameters passed through from the main report. "NotYetPickedUpByAgent" is the example we've been discussing here. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bqGcD.png)

Comment: can you post screenshots of your parameter which gives your error and also expression of your calculated field which gives "YES/NO"

Comment: perfect now one more thing, can you post screenshot/expression of your Filter for Dataset1, How are you filtering data in your Dataset1.

Also your  parameter "NotYetPickedUp" is hidden, how are you setting Yes or No or all for that parameter?

Comment: Thank you - I've updated the post with some screenshots. It might be that the answer is simply it can't be done, I'm OK with that.

Comment: so you are always passing "YES" as parameter to your Subreport? I think you also have some Filtering on Your sub-report data set?
Problem probably lies how you take parameter from Main report and add it to your Subreport filter. More info abour subreport dataset will add info

Comment: For that parameter I would always pass YES - it's a value in a calculated column and is passed as a default value.. I think the issue is multiple parameters on the subreport dataset but only one of them applies in each case. Not sure SSRS knows how to resolve that. I'll update the main post.

Comment: You have 3 filters on your sub-report datastet.  Are you sure that issue is only with "NotYetPickedUp" parameter and not other? To narrow down the issue, I would first remove all filter and try to run the report see if error occurs, Then try adding 1 parameter and so on with all 3

Comment: So I decided to start from scratch, binned all the filters and calculated columns and re-created them and added them in one by one, to make sure the data types lined up in the column and in the parameter. It now works! I think you were right and it must have been one of the other filters. I have a further question, for drill throughs to work do you always have to specify the default values of the parameter or can that be omitted?

Comment: You don’t need default value for the subreport to work. By the way I will add my findings during comments as answer, could you please mark it as solved. It will help others as well

Comment: I'm afraid that that didn't actually work now I've tested it with small data sets. The drill through actions work now because the parameters and values are the same data type, but the filters don't apply correctly. As soon as I add more that one filter on the dataset, they are all applied, not selectively in response to which parameter is applied through the action. I can't find a way around it, there's an Omit option on the action, but that only seems to omit values from the same column/parameter and I have lots of filters on many columns.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please go through each of your parameters one by one.

I would suggest deleting all the filters and trying to run the report and subreport.
Then keep adding filter one by one.

I think issue can be any of the filter and not the one you think.